# Text view with Image in RecyclerView but text is wrapped like a Paragraph

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've searched a lot for this topic, but i didn't found what i really want to achieve, i will try to explain:

- I have a list with `image` and a `text`.
- the text can be long to take one or more lines whatever.
- first i will put the image then the text beside and so on...
- sure i want to make every item clickable (like the image below).

Here's an example of image taken from an app that i want to develop the same idea that i want:

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `SpannableString` and `ImageSpan`. First, you need to have drawable of it and using `setSpan` method. This is an example format space after "span" word to icon.

```
 SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Bottom: span.\nBaseline: span.");
 // using the default alignment: ALIGN_BOTTOM
 string.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher), 7, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 string.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),
 22, 23, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

[image]

Comment: i know this solution but can't do more
1- i need an example with list of items text and link with images
2- every item should be clickable